# Slack is autoremoving after reboot for no reason

Tags: 18.04, slack

I have slack installed. Installed package with dpkg.
After every single reboot/shutdown it just disappears from system. This happens only with slack. I have to reinstall it every single system launch, i am tired. How to fix this?
Why application removes after every reboot, is this even legal?!

Comment: Questions of legality aside, are you running Ubuntu from a Live USB session?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy slack-desktop`, `snap list | grep slack` and `sudo apt-get check`?